# what wrong with this query?

Tags: sql

im trieng to select data from 3 diffrent tables, i want to select the data and filter it that the fullname dont apper twice and the number of order from this fullname will grouped to one. i tried these query but it gave me an error, can you help me?

```
SELECT 
   `biz`.`id`, 
   `deals`.`biz_id`,
   `deals`.`id` as `deal_id`,
   `deals`.`name`, 
   `orders`.`id`,
   `users`.`username`,
   `users`.`fullname`,
   `users`.`id` as `user_id`,
   `orders`.`dealid`, 
   `orders`.`userid` ,
    COUNT(`orders`.`userid`) as `num` 
FROM 
  `deals`,
  `users`,
  `orders` 
WHERE 
  `deals`.`biz_id` = '{$User['id']}' 
  AND `orders`.`dealid` = `deal_id` 
  AND `users_id` = `deals`.`userid`
```

Comment: And why did you add a PHP tag, unless you add some PHP code?

Comment: Is the data in `$User['id']` correct? Btw, you are doing a double Cartesian Product in that query meaning you are creating a table with m*n*p rows where m,n, and p are the number of rows in each table. That could be very CPU intensive to do very often, I think it might help you to look into `joins` to avoid that.

Comment: FYI, you are likely open to SQL injection.  Look into using prepared queries with PDO.  Of course, it is hard to know for sure without actually seeing your code.

Comment: Unknown column 'biz.id' in 'field list'

Comment: there is no possible why to do SQL INJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement, the first field you are selecting is 'id' field from 'biz' table. However, 'biz' table is not in your FROM clause.

I think I can guess how to fix it:

```
SELECT 
   `biz`.`id`, 
   `deals`.`biz_id`,
   `deals`.`id` as `deal_id`,
   `deals`.`name`, 
   `orders`.`id`,
   `users`.`username`,
   `users`.`fullname`,
   `users`.`id` as `user_id`,
   `orders`.`dealid`, 
   `orders`.`userid` ,
    COUNT(`orders`.`userid`) as `num` 
FROM 
  `biz`,
  `deals`,
  `users`,
  `orders` 
WHERE 
  `deals`.`biz_id` = '{$User['id']}' 
  AND `biz`.`id` = `deals`.`biz_id`
  AND `orders`.`dealid` = `deal_id` 
  AND `users_id` = `deals`.`userid`
GROUP BY `orders`.`userid
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial error is the result of the fact that there is no table called **biz** in the `from` clause to select the **id** field from.

Also, this query will also fail at the `count()` function as there is no `group by` clause and this is not an aggregate function.

Answer (score -1):

```
FROM
```

`deals`,
  `users`,
  `orders`

I dont think you can do that. You need to join tables, in this case you need two joins to join 3 tables. It will be a more complicted query then this.

Comment: While inadvisable for a join, it is not syntactically necessary to actually identify it as such.

Comment: sooo anyone can help me assmble the query?